# What does Hodgekins' "Northerne speech" mean?

Tags: thomas-deloney, thomas-of-reading

In chapter IV of Thomas Deloney's "novel" *Thomas of Reading*, king [Henry I of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_I_of_England) is willing to grant the clothiers a few requests as a reward for their support during a military campaign in France. Hodgekins, a clothier from [Halifax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halifax,_West_Yorkshire) (Yorkshire), requests that the town of Halifax be allowed to hang thieves who steal "Clothes". While the king is saying he is willing to grant the request, Hodgekins interrupts him:

> With that Hodgekins unmannerly interrupted the King, saying in broad Northerne speech, Yea gude faith, mai Liedge, the faule eule of mai saule, giff any thing will keepe them whiat, till the karles be hanged by the cragge. What the dule care they for boaring their eyne, sea lang as they mae gae groping up and down the Country like fause lizar lownes, begging and craking?

Most of this understandable, but not all of it (in bold):

> (...) Yes, good faith, my [liege](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liege#Noun), the foul **eule** of my soul, give anything [that] will keep them **whiatt**, till the [karls](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/karl#Noun)/guys are hanged by the **cragge** (neck?). What the [dule](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dule#Noun) (or devil?) care they for **boaring** their eyes, so/as long as they may go groping up and down the country like false **lizar** [lownes (i.e. loons)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lowne), begging and [craking (crying out loudly?)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crake#Verb).

"Boaring their eyne" posssibly means blinding them (the English verb [bore](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bore#Etymology_1) is a cognate of German [bohren](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bohren)), though I am not aware of this being a punishment for theft in medieval England. Who can fill in the gaps and confirm that my other guesses are correct?

Comment: Nice one! Even today a broad Northern England accent can be hard to understand for southerners; add a few centuries of time difference and you get a real challenge :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**eule:** evil; it seems to have been spelled *Evle* in [some editions](https://books.google.com/books?id=WbkvAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA45&lpg=PA45&dq=%22Hodgekins+unmannerly+interrupted+the+King%22&source=bl&ots=3VrBj2NJ7W&sig=ACfU3U1_MK6rhLH6zc5V6FAPdP09TE4cHA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjsosayke_iAhXHq1kKHT9kAZgQ6AEwAHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).

**whiatt:** probably *quiet*, as pronounced in a Northern dialect. In Scottish speech, *qu* and *wh* were the same sound, /xw/. It was usually spelled *qu* in Scotland, though, but that spelling wouldn't have conveyed the Northern pronunciation. [See this ELU.stackexchange answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/80312/5754).

**karl:** The OED has a bunch of definitions for *carl*, which range from *fellow* to something like *penny-pincher*. The most likely meaning, based on the date and the context, is "A fellow of low birth or rude manners; a base fellow; a churl. In later times, passing into a vague term of disparagement or contempt, and chiefly with appropriate epithets."

**cragge:** indeed, neck. (What else would you be hanged by?) The OED has "crag: The neck. (Chiefly Scottish, but also English regional (northern).)"

**dule** devil: the OED says that this spelling was used in the 1500s, particularly "in representations of Scottish speech".

**boaring their eyes**: indeed, putting out their eyes. From the OED "bore: To pierce, stab, run through with a weapon; to wound. *Obsolete*."

**lizar:** From the OED: *lazar (adj.)*: Affected with a loathsome disease, esp. leprosy; leprous. Or maybe it's the noun *lazar*: *somebody afflicted with a loathsome disease ...,* since *false leper louts* (louts who pretend to be lepers) makes a little more sense.

**craking:** After some discussion—see the comments—it seems that *craking* means to make noise using a clapper (also called a *crake*) that lepers carried to warn people to keep away from them.

So translated into modern English, the passage reads

> Yes, good faith, my liege, the foul evil of my soul, give anything [that] will keep them quiet, till the karles (oafs) be hanged by the cragge (neck). What the devil do they care for boaring (putting out) their eyes, so long as they may go groping up and down the Country like fause lizar lownes (false leper louts), begging and craking (rattling).

Comment: Thanks; +1. I hadn't made the connection between lizar and lazar. I now wonder whether craking can also refer to the noise that lepers were required to make to announce their presence (using a [bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leprosy#Middle_Ages) or a clapper or, in some countries apparently, a [ratchet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratchet_(instrument))).

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe: I think you must be right about *crake*. The [*Monthly Chronicle of **North-Country** Lore and Legend*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Z7c_AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA466&dq=crake+leper&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3rN7Y4vDiAhWCpZ4KHTUlCu8Q6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q&f=false)  (1889, but describing the Middle Ages) has *The wretched, but unfortunate, suppliants [begging lepers] ... carried in their hands a wooden clapper or crake, somewhat like that used by crow-herds to scare away rooks from the cornfields, with which they rattled so as to attract attention.*

Comment: Excellent find :-)

Comment: Is "lazar" cognate with Lazarus, by any chance? Apparently Lazarus is sometimes called the patron saint of leprosy.

Comment: @Rand al'Thor: indeed, *lazar* is derived from *Lazarus*.